# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $C$ a compact subset, and $K$ a closed subset. Prove that $K \cap C = \emptyset$ iff $d(K,C) > 0$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $C$ a compact subset, and $K$ a closed subset. Prove that $K \cap C = \emptyset$ iff $d(K,C) > 0$.

For this problem I was going to consider $d(x,F) = \inf d(x,y)$ for $y \in F$ where $\{x : d(x,F) = 0 \} = \overline{F}$.

Comment: $d(K,C) = \inf \{ d(x,K) : x \in C\}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let
$$d(x,K)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in K\}.$$
Check that $d(x,K)>0$ for each $x\in C$, and apply extreme value theorem.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for edit, but I think your edit is inadequate so I rollback it. To apply extreme value theorem, we need a real-valued function with compact domain.

Comment: Note that there is no $F$ in the problem statement

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah, I confused it.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in C$, we have that $x \notin K$, so there is an $r_x > 0$ such that $B(x, r_x) \cap K = \emptyset$ (as $K$ is closed). The set $\{B(x, \frac{r_x}{2}): x \in C \}$ forms an open cover of $C$, so finitely many of them cover $C$, as $C$ is compact, say $B(x_1, {r_{x_1} \over 2}),\ldots, B(x_N, {r_{x_N} \over 2})$ cover $C$, and let $r =\min(\frac{r_{x_1}}{2},\ldots,\frac{r_{x_N}}{2}) > 0$.

Now suppose that for some $y \in K, x \in C$, $d(x,y) < r$. Then for some $i \in \{1,\ldots,N\}$, $d(x_i, x) < \frac{r_{x_i}}{2}$, and then $d(x_i, y) \le d(x_i, x) + d(x, y) < \frac{r_{x_i}}{2} + r \le r_{x_i}$, which contradicts the way $r_{x_i}$ was chosen.

So in conclusion, $\forall_{x \in C}, \forall_{y \in K}: d(x,y) \ge r$, which implies $d(C,K) \ge r > 0$.